# DnD Files / upload ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on an HTML Form that captures input from users and allows to upload multiple files. I am making use of HTML 5 File API.

My question is, when using File Input, I specify 'multiple' and then I access all files on server (ASP.NET). However, when allowing user to Drag and Drop files instead, how are those files going to be sent to server when submitting the Form without using jQuery or Ajax, simple Form submit.

Thanks